# Updating counter in a file from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, gawk

I have a txt file which has the stats of file transfered to diff remote machines as mentioned below

```
172.31.32.5 yes 2
172.31.32.6 yes 3
```

Now when 3 more files are transferred to first machine i want the file to be updated to below from a shell script

```
172.31.32.5 yes 5
172.31.32.6 yes 3
```

I was planning to use some thing like this

```
sed -i '/$IP/d' /tmp/fileTrnsfr
echo "$IP yes $((oldcount + newcount))
```

But looking for a better solution which would search, update and replace using sed or awk commands

Comment: What did you try for yourself? (And) How does the script know if files are transferred?

Comment: I am using "rsync" for file transfer. I have the no of file transferred in a shell variable.

Comment: Can u pls check updated edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Awk` to achieve this. You need to import the variables containing the IP information and number of files to the context fo `Awk` and modify it.

```
temp_file="$(mktemp)"
awk -v ip="$ip" -v count="$newcount" '$1==ip{$NF+=count}1' /tmp/fileTrnsfr > "$temp_file" && mv "$temp_file" /tmp/fileTrnsfr
```

The `mktemp` is for creating a temporary name used to write the contents of `Awk` and move it back the original file name (simulation for the in-place file edit)

The above is for older non GNU variants of `Awk` which do not support in-place edit.

In latest GNU Awk (since [4.1.0 released](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.awk/browse_thread/thread/40ce7554f025c382)), it has the option of ["inplace" file editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html):

> [...] The "inplace" extension, built using the new facility, can be used to simulate the GNU "`sed -i`" feature. [...]

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -v ip="$ip" -v count="$newcount" '$1==ip{$NF+=count}1' /tmp/fileTrnsfr
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires GNU sed:

```
$ cat fileTrnsfr 
172.31.32.5 yes 2
172.31.32.6 yes 3

$ newcount=3
$ ip=172.31.32.5

$ sed -i -r '
    /^'"${ip//./\\.}"'/ {
        s/(.*) ([[:digit:]]+)/printf "%s %d" "\1" "$(expr \2 + '"$newcount"')"/
        e
    }
' fileTrnsfr 

$ cat fileTrnsfr 
172.31.32.5 yes 5
172.31.32.6 yes 3
```

That transforms the line

```
172.31.32.5 yes 2
```

into

```
printf "%s %d" "172.31.32.5 yes" "$(expr 2 + 3)"
```

and then uses the `e` command to execute it as a command (using /bin/sh, I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Entirely native in portable POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

# read data from arguments (or else standard input), line by line
cat "${@:-/dev/stdin}" |while read line; do
  number="${line##*[^0-9]}"  # extract the number at the end of the line
  line="${line%$number}"     # remove that number from the end of the line
  echo "$line$((number+3))"  # append (number+3) to the end of the line
done
```